# How do I deal with iterating over a one to many (or zero) entity when there are zero/null entry?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I keep getting `NullReferenceException` trying to iterate over a null entry on a row.

```
public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
    }

public class Address
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstLine { get; set; }
        public string SecondLine { get; set; }
    }
```

With the default scaffold template, `_context.Person.Include(c => c.Address);`

The view works fine if there is an address or not.

However, I'm now replacing the default index page with a newer grid that loads via AJAX with filtering and paging mechanism. For this, I need to convert the data to my ViewModel

I want to be able to display the address in line as text. I've tried the following:

```
        var tmp = _context.Person.Include(x => x.Address).ToList();

        tmp.ForEach(x => vm.List.Add(new IndexListItem()
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Address = x.Address.FirstLine + " " + x.Address.SecondLine,
            ID = x.ID

        }));
```

But, when debugging, Address seems to always be null, even if there is data on the row.

I'm pretty sure I can do this on a standard foreach loop, and doing an if null check, but, I can't help but feel this is something that is quite simple and I'm over complicating it.

Is there a simpler way to return the address details I need?

Comment: Seems impossible that the same query behaves differently in two situations. Note however that it's far more efficient to project to the view model directly by `_context.Person.Select(p => new IndexListItem {Name = p.Name, Address = p.Address.FirstLine + " " + p.Address.SecondLine, ... }`.

Comment: Hi Gert, sorry if I wasn't clear - using the default scaffold view/controller, I never try to enumerate address before the view handles it. It is only since I modify and try to put the address to a string that I get the error. I'm guessing it is because I've already called tolist or similar. But thank you also for your comment. I'm still very much a novice and performance/best practice is something that I really want to understand better (after I have learnt how to actually make it work!!)

Comment: Can you try the address like this: Address = x.Address?.FirstLine + " " + x.Address?.SecondLine,

Comment: I think that was clear. It's just that the part `_context.Person.Include(c => c.Address)` didn't seem to change and that should always do the same thing.

Comment: @sriharsha - I feel like such a noob - I didn't know you call nullable strings like that to get rid of the error... That works great - feel free to put it as an answer... Bonus points if you can tell me how I can get rid of the white space/only display it if there is  something I need to separate to its left! (but will probably do that in the view...)

Comment: can you please keep it in question of what you mean to get rid of white space data.

Comment: @sriharsha - I meant, what you have done is great, but, I now get "   " returned instead of null... is there any easy way to do the same sort of check on the whitespace? or do I need to do something along the lines of ... + address ?? null + or I am returning the whitespace only.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment, you should do this in one statement:

```
vm.List = _context.Person
    .Select(p => new IndexListItem
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        Address = p.Address.FirstLine + " " + p.Address.SecondLine,
        ID = p.ID
    }).ToList();
```

This has two advantages:

1. It's translated into SQL, so only the four required fields are pulled from the database (which makes a considerable difference with wider records).
2. EF will generate SQL that takes null values into account.

If you don't want `" "` as result you could do...

```
Address = (p.Address.FirstLine + " " + p.Address.SecondLine).Trim()
```

...or...

```
Address = p.Address.FirstLine != null ? p.Address.FirstLine + " " : "")
    + p.Address.SecondLine
```

But I don't think it matters much for viewing data.

Comment: Thanks - ok, so, I now fully understand what is going on and why (the other answer on this post fixes it, but the other question goes in to detail and explains the problem)... This answer is great for performance, but, doesn't address the issue (If you can edit/do Address? -  I can mark as answer and the performance boost is a bonus!). However... I'm also curious if there is ***any*** syntax I can use on a single line to return null/remove the whitespace within the select function? I've tried ` x.Address?.FirstLine + x.Address ?? x.Address : null `  and some others without luck :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "If you can edit/do Address?", but here's anther way to add the space conditionally in a one-liner (sort of). There are no other/shorter options.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the address like this:

```
Address = x.Address?.FirstLine + " " + x.Address?.SecondLine,
```

If you don't want white-space, try like below:

```
Address = x.Address == null ? null : (x.Address.FirstLine + " " + x.Address.SecondLine),
```