# Why doesn't a null cause a NullReferenceException when mapping to and from a null type?

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I'm basically trying to iterate over a lot of data and transform a returned data query to a more limited object within a View Model.

Rather than do a huge section of code, I'm calling .ForEach() on a list, then adding a new entry to the view model's list.

This works great, but, there is one property (Address) that is optional.

When I reach the optional item, I get `NullReferenceException` if the item from the DB doesn't have an entry.

A code example is:

```
    var tmp = _context.Person.Include(x => x.Address).ToList();

    tmp.ForEach(x => vm.List.Add(new IndexListItem()
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Address = x.Address.FirstLine + " " + x.Address.SecondLine,
        ID = x.ID

    }));
```

I have since found out from a different answer on this site that if I change the address line so that it reads:

```
        Address = x.Address?.FirstLine + " " + x.Address?.SecondLine,
```

The code now works when I hit a null entry in `tmp`.

I do not understand this as the Address property on `tmp` was already allowing nulls, and the Address property on the view model allows nulls, so, why does changing the line suddenly not return an error?

In addition, is the reason for me not having to do `x.Address?.FirstLine?` because that's a string and strings are already nullable?

Comment: @camiloTerevinto - I see the edit, and am happy with linq, but, this isn't really to do with Entity Framework per se.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - It's more generic though... I'm not using Entity Framework, whilst I am sure I will get the same with it, I'm using NHibernate...

Comment: Usually, if the address is `null`, you don't want a string with a space in it!

Comment: @Phil1970 - Another question for another day! ... well. I think I have it working - I now use Address = ParseAddress(x.Address) and have a null checked in that method, but, the main thing I asked here was the bit that was annoying me that I wanted an answer for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A null reference exception *in this particular case* is caused when you are trying to access a property where the parent object is null itself.

```
x.Address.FirstLine
```

i.e. in your case Address is null.

It is not in regard to what you are trying to set (i.e. the destination view model).

The reason that this works:

```
x.Address?.FirstLine
```

..is because 'in the background' it's checking first to see if `Address` is null. If it isn't, then it returns `FirstLine` and if it is, then null is returned. It's semantically equivalent to:

```
if (x.Address == null)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return x.Address.FirstLine;
}
```

Here's a blog post about the introduction of the ?. operator in C# for some background reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/

Comment: Thank you so much - Expanding that code and your above explanation suddenly makes this make sense to me.

Comment: @DevX glad to be of assistance :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand this as the Address property on tmp was already allowing nulls, and the Address property on the view model allows nulls, so, why does changing the line suddenly not return an error?

You are mixing up saving data with loading data. When you save the data to the database, `null` is acceptable, but when you try to use the data, `null` is not.

The [null conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator (`?.`) allows you to "shorten" an `if` statement, and it would be something similar to:

```
Address = x.Address?.FirstLine + " " + x.Address?.SecondLine,

string Address = "";
if (x.Address != null)
{
    Address += x.Address.FirstLine;
}
// ....
```

Also, while not relevant to your problem, the code you are using is extremely ineffective, you are loading 2 tables to get just a few properties when you could get those properties directly from the database:

```
var vm = _context.Person
    .Select(x => new IndexListItem
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Address = x.Address?.FirstLine + " " + x.Address?.SecondLine,
        ID = x.ID
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I'm going to accept Alex's answer as it explains the issue slightly better (and, it really is a question where I am trying to learn about Nulls, not loading/saving data..), but, I love your example of how to make the code better - so, thank you and I will upvote once I get 15 rep.

Comment: You can't use the null propagation operator in expressions. But see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281528/861716): it's not necessary. We both gave about the same answer because I wasn't aware of this question.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for that. I've upvoted you and marked as duplicate. 4 answers when you already answered...

Comment: OK, thanks, but I think this question is slightly different: here it's not about the NRE itself, but the working of the `?` operator.

Comment: I'm learning and this is a different issue using the same code example... That answer was only just written and yes it's the same in your answer - and I'm thankful to learn, but in neither question am I asking to improve the code. The first question was about a fix to the code (where I learnt about doing class?) and this question was simple... with the code working as it is, why does a nullable object behave like it does - and it has been answered very well above.

Comment: @GertArnold Absolutely - Thanks for understanding, and thank you for your answer in the other question.

Comment: @DevX Beware there, those are not the best words to use. There's no such thing as a "nullable object" (an object reference is the opposite to a null reference), you need to be careful with your words. Any reference type can be null though. That should have been thought way before anything as advanced as NHibernate

Answer (score 2):

`x.Address?.FirstLine` where `?` is null propogation operator this means if `x.Address` is `null` set `null` for the `FirstLine`.

null propogation equivalent code

```
if (x.Address == null)
   return null
else 
   return x.Address.FirstLine
```

---

All reference type variables are nullable. hence, assigning null to reference types are always valid.

`string` is a reference-type in your example. therefore you do not get error because `string x = null` is valid

Answer (score 1):

Your issue isn't that `Address` is null and you're trying to assign it to another property that allows null, it's that you're trying to access `.FirstLine` in something that's null.

If `Address` is null, then what you're trying to do with `.FirstLine` is the equivalent of `null.FirstLine` which doesn't work. Nothing can't hold something.

The `?` notation you're using that works is only effecting `Address`, basically saying if `Address` is **NOT** null give me the value of `.FirstLine`, if it is null, then give me null.